# INSERT a SET<String> into cassandra by passing through a variable

Tags: scala, cassandra, cql, datastax-java-driver

```
INSERT INTO devices (id,dataformat,device_type_id,protocol_id,tags) VALUES ('asd','asdas','sad','asdas',{'asd','as'});
```

This one works perfectly while passing the SET in the CQL but while passing the SET using the code below it shows

```
Invalid value Set(asd, assd) of type unknown to the query builder
```

Code that i used,

```
val statement: Statement = (QueryBuilder.insertInto("devices")).value("id",model.deviceId)
    .value("device_type_id",model.deviceType).value("protocol_id",model.protocol)
    .value("dataformat",model.dataFormat).value("tags",model.tag)
client.executeQuery(statement)
client.close()
```

The model is of

```
case class AddDeviceRequestModel(deviceId: String, deviceType: String, protocol: String,
                             dataFormat: String, tag: Set[String])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, you are using [Datastax's JavaDriver QueryBuilder](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/2.0/java-driver/reference/queryBuilderOverview.html). If that is the case, then you are using a Java library which expects Java types in its interface.

For atomic types, that is all your fields except `tag`'s type, it works because atomic type Scala-Java interoperability. However it isn't that easy for collection classes such as `Set`.

You need to use [Scala Java Conversion](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.JavaConversions$)'s `setAsJavaSet` in order to pass the set value:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions.setAsJavaSet

val statement: Statement =(QueryBuilder.insertInto("devices")).value("id",model.deviceId)     .value("device_type_id",model.deviceType).value("protocol_id",model.protocol)
.value("dataformat",model.dataFormat).value("tags",setAsJavaSet(model.tag))

client.executeQuery(statement)
client.close()
```

Comment: It Worked , Thanks :)